How to write an efficient mongo query for complex structures
I am using express/nodejs(without mongoose) and mongodb as my database. I have a collection Pages which looks something like this
{
  _id: ..
  Urls: [
    {
      IncomingUrl: "/test/test1",
      Status: "active",
    },
    {
      IncomingUrl: "/test/test2",
      Status: "active",
    }
  ],
  DraftUrls: [
    // same structure as Urls
  ] 
  //other fields which arent related to the ques
}


Now while creating a page i am looking through this collection to find if any url in the urls array i am providing in the body of request is already existing in any existing page document.
And if there is a duplicate url then provide a list of duplicate urls in response.
Now the problem i am facing is that if i just had to get the count i could've used a find filter like
const filter = { $or: [
  { "Urls.IncomingUrl": { $in: urls } },
  { "DraftUrls.IncomingUrl": { $in: urls } }
] }

And then used a query like
db.collection(PageCollection).find(filter).countDocuments();

And it wouldve given the count of duplicate urls
But in my case i need to get the duplicate urls rather than the count so if i use something like this
const duplicateUrlPages = db.collection(PageCollection).find(filter).toArray();

And then run a nested for loop over the urls and duplicateUrlPages then it would be too costly.
Could someone please suggest how could i efficiently get just the list of urls among the input urls that are already existing in any Page document under its Urls.IncomingUrl or DraftUrls.IncomingUrl
Example:
Suppose there are 2 document like this in my DB
Document1: {
  // ....
  Urls: [ 
    { IncomingUrl: "test1", status: "active" }, 
    // ... 
  ],
  DraftUrls: [
    { IncomingUrl: "test2", status: "inactive" },
    // ...
  ]
}

Document2: {
  // ....
  Urls: [ 
    { IncomingUrl: "test4", status: "active" }, 
    // ... 
  ],
  DraftUrls: [
    { IncomingUrl: "test10", status: "inactive" },
    // ...
  ]
}

And I provide the body to a POST request controller function as
{
  // ...
  urls: ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"]
}

Then i want a response array like:
["test1", "test2", "test4"]

Since test1, test2 and test4 already exist

what do you mean by duplicate urls. can you give an example

@cmgchess i mentioned that while creating a page i am providing a urls array. Before creating the page i am checking if any of these urls are already present in the DB under either Urls.IncomingUrl or DraftUrls.IncomingUrl. If yes i need all those urls as a list.

@cmgchess provided the example at question's end

You may want to refactor and flatten the URLs arrays into individual documents like pagesUrl collection in this playground, since you are operating a lot at the URL level. You can also index the IncomingUrl field to boost performance

@ray i understand what youre trying to say but i cant refactor it since i need to separate live and draft urls as Urls and DraftUrls (its a requirement for the project). And yes ive implemented indexing for IncomingUrl within Urls and DraftUrls. Anyway thanks for the suggestions.

@JayendraAwasthi You can see the isDraft flag in the new document structure. Sorry for the typo in previous playground. Here is the correct one.

@ray yes i got it that i can use a flag to store both live and draft urls under PageUrls. But as i said i cant change the existing structure of the collection since many other feature are dependent on it.

You can use an aggregation.

$match: replicates your $or conditions filter object.
$project: reshape the documents by $filter-ing the setting Urls and DraftUrls arrays to only contain matches from your $match conditions. In essence this will get rid of objects such as those containing test10 in your sample documents.
$project: output the Urls and DraftUrls as a single array named urls.
$unwind: the new urls array into individual objects.
$group: these new objects and add the values to a single array using $addToSet to ensure no duplicates.
$project: optional stage to get rid of the redundant _id field.

const urls = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"];

const filter = { $or: [
  { "Urls.IncomingUrl": { $in: urls } },
  { "DraftUrls.IncomingUrl": { $in: urls } }
] }

db.collection(PageCollection).aggregate([
  {
    $match: filter
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "Urls": {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$Urls",
              as: "u",
              cond: {
                $in: [
                  "$$u.IncomingUrl",
                  urls
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          as: "rls",
          in: "$$rls.IncomingUrl"
        }
      },
      "DraftUrls": {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$DraftUrls",
              as: "du",
              cond: {
                $in: [
                  "$$du.IncomingUrl",
                  urls
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          as: "drls",
          in: "$$drls.IncomingUrl"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      urls: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$DraftUrls",
          "$Urls"
        ]
      },
      _id: 0
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$urls"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      urls: {
        $addToSet: "$urls"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])

See HERE for a working example.

Thanks, i already had posted my solution similar to this aggregation but yesterday some ”great minds” thought of deleting my answer from my own post just because i mentioned “i would like to know if i can optimise this answer furthur” :) . Anyways thanks for the help, i will mark this as the solution since its almost same as my ans.

Perhaps you might get some luck if you post your answer as another question. That way, someone would be able to answer that question with a more optimised answer. Aggregations can always be optimised but best to specify your parameters i.e faster, using less stages or where to implement indexes etc.

sure…will post it when i get time. Thanks
